# Delaying Cocoa NSDocument creation at startup

Tags: cocoa, subprocess, nsdocument

I have a document-based Cocoa application that has to start up a sub-process before running. It would be best if that process could finish starting up before I display any document windows. I get a notification when the process has fully started.

How can I delay the creation of the untitled NSDocument subclass object until the notification arrives? I have a splash screen and a timeout, so I can "busy wait" and still get user-generated events. I can override any class I need to.

Comment: Don't use splash screens; they suck.

Comment: Have to agree with that one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [-applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW39) delegate method. You can say "NO" and create the untitled document on your own when you're ready with the following code:

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] newDocument:self];
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I wait for the notification to come in, and I call the above code.
Thank you.